# Given a triangle $ABC$, with altitude $AD$ and circumcircle radius $R$, show that $AD = 2R\sin\ B\sin\ C$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a triangle $ABC$, with altitude $AD$ and circumcircle radius $R$, show that $$AD = 2R\sin\ B\sin\ C.$$

I'm a bit stumped as to how the altitude of $ABC$ and the circumcircle radius interact with each other, perhaps something to do with the Euler Line?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't realize I could format in that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Circumcircle_equations) I get

$$R=\frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{2\sin C}$$

and you can also express the other sine as a fraction

$$\sin B=\frac{\lvert AD\rvert}{\lvert AB\rvert}$$

Then you combine these and cancel stuff:

$$2R\sin B\sin C =
2\frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{2\sin C}\frac{\lvert AD\rvert}{\lvert AB\rvert}\sin C
=\lvert AD\rvert
$$

So the interaction between the altitude and the circumcircle appears to be mostly due to the fact that the altitude can be used to express $\sin B$.

If I had to proove that formula from Wikipedia, I'd probably do so using the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) like this:

[image: Illustration]

If the interior angle $\angle ACB$ is $\theta$, then the central angle $AOB=2\theta$, and since $\triangle ABO$ is isosceles, if you take $E$ to be the midpoint of $AB$, then $\triangle OEB$ is a right triangle with $\angle EOB=\theta$ again. So there you have $\lvert EB\rvert = \lvert OB\rvert\sin\theta = R\sin\theta$ and $\lvert AB\rvert=2\lvert EB\rvert = 2R\sin\theta = 2R\sin C$.